# Can I view Rails documentation with pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

Is it possible to view/browse Rails documentation with pry? How?

(pry-rails appears to be for project source, and pry-doc covers Core Ruby.)

Is ri the preferred local doc browsing tool for Rails?

Thanks!

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Documentation-browsing) of any use?

Comment: @August, that's where I've been looking, but while `show-doc Pry::Method` works, `show-doc ActiveRecord::Base`, for example, doesn't.

Comment: @SexxLuthor you may not have that documentation. Does ActiveRecord show up when you run `gem server`?

Comment: @D-side, it does, but no doc link. I guess the doc is ri-dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pry will only show you documentation for dependencies that you have explicitly loaded. The easiest way to get all the Rails dependencies is to run pry in a Rails project's directory like so:

```
pry -r ./config/environment
```

Now you're ready to see Rails' internal documentation through pry. However, as you noted Rails' documentation is written with ri in mind. So instead of using `show-doc` if you run `ri ActiveRecord::Base` you should see:

```
ActiveRecord::Base < Object

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Includes:
(from gem activerecord-4.1.1)
  Core
  Persistence
  NoTouching
  ReadonlyAttributes
  ModelSchema
  Inheritance
  Scoping
  Sanitization
  AttributeAssignment
  ActiveModel::Conversion
  Integration
  Validations
.... it eventually gets to the actual documentation but you get the idea ...
```

(I believe `show-doc` does not work for `ActiveRecord::Base` because there's a `#:nodoc:` directive in that file's source code. Perhaps someone can chime in in the comments or add an edit.)

Alternatively, you can load each dependency you want manually. If you opened up a normal pry session and run `require 'active_record'` the same `ri` command will work.

This should work with the rails console as well if you use the pry-rails gem or a custom initializer to set pry as the default REPL.

Comment: Thanks, I guess pry is dependent on ri? I also realized afterward that ActiveRecord::Base wasn't the best example--probably Core would be a better one. It seems to work without 'require' as well (on a different machine with ri/doc not being excluded). Does `show-doc` work at all with Rails? Only the ri method seems to.

Comment: And thanks, @Yoshiki. (The question is mostly about how/if other devs are using pry with Rails documentation, or just using ri or http://api.rubyonrails.org/.)

Comment: I think it depends on the `:nodoc:` flag. Take a look at base.rb from active_record: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L26

Pry probably respects the `:nodoc:` directive in the context of `show-doc` but has different rules when using `ri`. Why is it doing that? Why does Rails have a nodoc directive on base.rb? I can't say I'm sure, since I lack familiarity with rdoc in general. If you're really curious I would recommend asking around the rails irc channel or the #pry irc channel.

Comment: Also @SexxLuthor I know for a fact that `show-doc` will work with `ActiveRecord::Validations`.